# Scrum fixed date planning, number of sprints

Tags: scrum, scrumboard

For fixed date planning with a 2 Weeks sprint, I will determine how many sprints I have between two dates, April 1, 2020, and June 4, 2020. The number of weeks between the two dates is 9, 1 weeks. Does this mean there are 4,5 sprints?

Comment: is this a question about writing a sw planning app or is it about how scrum works?

Comment: Thank you for your reponse. It's just to understabd how it works. I got my hand on a scrum training material, where in the exercice the results were 13 weeks and 6,5 sprints. However when I calculated it my self, the results were different.

Comment: you want https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I advise that there is no such thing as half a Sprint and to round to a whole number. So, for your calculation, I'd say you have four Sprints.